# error in ListView with image

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm trying to build a `ListView` in android, where each  item of `ListView` is composed for one `ImgeView` and 4 `TexView`. The `getView` of my class extended `BaseAdapter` is defined as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(vi == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_restaurantes, null);

      holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.nombreRestaurante= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.etiquetaNombreResItemRes);
         holder.direccionRestaurante = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.etiquetaDireccionResItemRes);
         holder.ciudadRestaurante = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.etiquetaCiudadResItemRes);
         holder.telefonoRestaurante = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.etiquetaTelResItemRes);
         holder.lineaLogo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.etiquetaLineaLogo);

         vi.setTag(holder);      
    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    itemRestaurante item= this.itemR.get(position);  

    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageLogoItemRestaurante);
    int imageResource = this.Activity.getResources().getIdentifier(item.getRutaImaLogo(), null, this.Activity.getPackageName());
    image.setImageDrawable(this.Activity.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource));        
    holder.nombreRestaurante.setText(item.getNombreR());        
    holder.direccionRestaurante.setText(item.getDireccionR());      
    holder.ciudadRestaurante.setText(item.getCiudadR());        
    holder.telefonoRestaurante.setText(item.getTelR());     
    holder.lineaLogo.setText(item.getDireccionR());

    return vi;
}
```

the code line on `getView`:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageLogoItemRestaurante);
    int imageResource = this.Activity.getResources().getIdentifier(item.getRutaImaLogo(), null, this.Activity.getPackageName());
    image.setImageDrawable(this.Activity.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource));
```

this is the  itemRestaurantes class where i return the rutaImagenLogo value

```
    package clasesExtras;

public class itemRestaurante {

    private long idRestaurante;
    private String nombreRestaurante;
    private String direccionRestaurante;
    private String ciudadRestaurante;
    private String telefonoRestaurante;
    private String rutaImagenLogo;
    //private String rutaImagenGo;
    //private String rutaImagenLineaLogo;

    /*Constructor*/
    public itemRestaurante(long id, String nombre, String direccion, String ciudad,
                            String telefono, String rutaLogo){

        this.idRestaurante= id;
        this.nombreRestaurante= nombre;
        this.direccionRestaurante= direccion;
        this.ciudadRestaurante= ciudad;
        this.telefonoRestaurante= telefono;
        this.rutaImagenLogo= rutaLogo;
        //this.rutaImagenGo= rutaGo;
        //this.rutaImagenLineaLogo = rutaLineaLogo;
    }


    public long getId(){        
        return this.idRestaurante;
    }

    public void setId(long id){     
        this.idRestaurante= id;
    }

    public String getNombreR(){     
        return this.nombreRestaurante;
    }

    public void setNombreR(String nombre){      
        this.nombreRestaurante=nombre;
    }

    public String getDireccionR(){      
        return this.direccionRestaurante;
    }

    public void setDireccionR(String direccion){
        this.direccionRestaurante=direccion;
    }

    public String getCiudadR(){
        return this.ciudadRestaurante;
    }

    public void setCiudadR(String ciudad){
        this.ciudadRestaurante= ciudad;
    }

    public String getTelR(){
        return this.telefonoRestaurante;
    }

    public void setTelR(String telefono){
        this.telefonoRestaurante= telefono;
    }

    public String getRutaImaLogo(){
        return this.rutaImagenLogo;
    }

    public void setRutaImaLogo(String imagenLogo){
        this.rutaImagenLogo= imagenLogo;
    }
```

this is the activity class where i fill the ArrayList with the information of each item of ListView

```
 package appetite.apptitud;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import clasesExtras.ArrayAdapterRestaurantes;
import clasesExtras.itemRestaurante;


public class ListaRestaurantes extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lista_restaurantes);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); //forza a android a ocultar el teclado virtual


        ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaRestaurantes);        
        ArrayList<itemRestaurante> itemRestaurante = obtenerItems();                
        ArrayAdapterRestaurantes adapter = new ArrayAdapterRestaurantes(this, itemRestaurante);

        lista.setAdapter(adapter);          



    }

    //Método para llenar la lista de los restaurantes.
    private ArrayList<itemRestaurante> obtenerItems(){
        ArrayList<itemRestaurante> items = new ArrayList<itemRestaurante>();

        items.add(new itemRestaurante(1, "Frisby", "Cra. 7a 24-74", "Pereira", "3168899", "drawable/frisby_logo"));
        items.add(new itemRestaurante(2, "Big Pollo", "Cra. 5a 34-12", "Pereira", "3147152", "drawable/bigpollo"));
        items.add(new itemRestaurante(3, "Wingz", "Cra. 8a 18-62", "Pereira", "3391000", "drawale/wingz"));
        items.add(new itemRestaurante(4, "Sir Pollo", "Cra. 7a 20-04", "Pereira", "3357913", "drawable/sirpollo"));

        return items;
    }
```

the code shown above make reference a the image path where it is stored (drawable folder), and i want to show this image  in each item of listview, but this jumps to the following error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
at clasesExtras.ArrayAdapterRestaurantes.getView(ArrayAdapterRestaurantes.java:56)
```

Some people tell me that the `imageResource` value is 0. And 0 is not a valid resource ID.
how can i do to fix this value?
Help me please, i don't understand it

Comment: Can you give a bit more information on how you're storing the image resources and how your code is referencing them.  What are some examples of what `item.getRutaImaLogo()` is supposed to return? It looks like you may be running into a problem because the images that method is pointing to do not exist.

Comment: Why not doing directry image.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_picture)?

Comment: I fixed it. I'm wrong while  i was building the image path when  i added the third item "itemRestaurante"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that imageResource is 0. Check this value.

> [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) Returns int The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)

Comment: how can i do to fix this value?

Comment: check getIdentifier param. Or better do not use it and get drawables by it's id. Change "drawable/frisby_logo" to R.drawable.frisby_logo, String rutaImagenLogo to int rutaImagenLogo. Use image.setImageDrawable(item.getRutaImaLogo()). It is faster and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom adapter for the list View

this would be Restaurant.java

```java
public class Restaurant{
   public int icon;
   public String someText;
   public String moreText;
   public String someMoreText;
   public String evenMoreText;

public Restaurant(int icon, String someText, String moreText, String somMoreText, String evenMoreText)
    super.();
    this.someText = someText;
    this.moreText = moreText;
    this.someMoreText = someMoreText;
    this.evenMoreText = evenMoreText;
    this.icon = icon;
}
```

Here is the custom adapter RestaurantAdapter.java

```
public class RestaurantAdapter extends<Restaurant> }
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Restaurant data[] = null;

    public RestaurantAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Restaurant[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RestaurantHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RestaurantHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtID1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtID1);
            holder.txtID2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtID2);
            holder.txtID3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtID3);
            holder.txtID4 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtID4);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (RestauantHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Restaurant restaurant = data[position];
        holder.txtID1.setText(restaurant.someText);
        holder.txtID1.setText(restaurant.moreText);
        holder.txtID1.setText(restaurant.someMoreText);
        holder.txtID1.setText(restaurant.evenMoreText);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(restarant.icon);

        return row;
    }
}   
static class RestaurantHolder
{
ImageView imgIcon;
TextView txtID1;
TextView txtID2;
TextView txtID3;
TextView txtID4;
}
```

Now in your activity it will be a call like this

```
    Restaurant restaurant_data[] = new Restaurant[]
    {
        new Restaurant(R.drawable.pic1, "some text", "more text", "some more text". "even more text"),
        new Restaurant(R.drawable.pic2, "text", "more", "some more", "blah"),
        new Restaurant(R.drawable.pic3, "blah1", "blah2", "blah3" "blah3"),
        new Restaurant(R.drawable.pic4, "you get the idea", "blah", "blah", "blah"),

    };

    RestaurantAdapter adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listview_item_row, restaurant_data);


    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Credit goes to http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429 
You will just have to change around some of the names.

Comment: i try to implement your example, but the `R.drawable.pic_name` in `decodeResource` only make reference at one image, and i have several images on my proyect.
what  can i do?